# Summarise in dplyr package: How to go around `Error: expecting a single value`

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a summary by ID, DRUG, FED summarising the sum of the `CONC` for `DVID =1` and `DVID==2`

```
df<- 
ID  DRUG  FED  DVID  CONC
1    1     1    1     20
1    1     1    2     40
2    2     0    1     30
2    2     0    2     100
```

I tried using this:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID,DRUG,FED) %>% 
  summarise(SumCOnc=CONC+lag(CONC))
```

However I am getting this error:

```
Error: expecting a single value
```

I don't get the error when I use `mutate`. Is there a way to go around it so I use `summarise` in the case described above?

The output should basically be this:

```
ID  DRUG  FED  SumConc
1    1     1    60
2    2     0    130
```

Comment: Along the same line. How can I specify the DVID for CONC in the code `SumCOnc=CONC+lag(CONC)`? The previous assumes that the data is already sorted for `ID,DRUG, FED` which might not be always the case. Is there a way to specify summing` CONC` for `DVID==1` and `DVID==2` given 'ID, FORM, FED`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward: just use `sum()`, don't mess around with `lag()` ...

Get data:

```
df<- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="
ID  DRUG  FED  DVID  CONC
1    1     1    1     20
1    1     1    2     40
2    2     0    1     30
2    2     0    2     100
")
```

Process:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID,DRUG,FED) %>% 
  summarise(SumConc=sum(CONC))

##      ID  DRUG   FED SumConc
## 1     1     1     1      60
## 2     2     2     0     130
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple Base R approach would be using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(CONC ~ ID + DRUG + FED, df, sum)

#  ID DRUG FED CONC
#1  2    2   0  130   
#2  1    1   1   60
```

Answer (score 4):

Or from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(SumConc = sum(CONC)), .(ID, DRUG, FED)]
#   ID DRUG FED SumConc
#1:  1    1   1      60
#2:  2    2   0     130
```